# Controls in dialog boxes are wrongly positioned

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS 2008+sp1 and just bought a fantastic HP envy with Win7. Many of my own programs, and other programs I use look terrible. The controls in dialog boxes seem to be thrown around.
Anybody with this experience - any advises are very helpful.

Comment: Should be on stackoverflow.com, not here.

Comment: @JNK - no reason, it's not programming related if it happens also with other programs than his. @user - can you describe more precisely your problem? Maybe provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Gnoupi - sorry, it sounded like he was asking how to move the boxes in his own programs he wrote in visual studio ("Many of my own programs...").